# MS Access 2010 Form Data Entry- Adding the Same Field to Multiple Entries

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

I created a table to keep track of shipments and the invoices associated with them. I'd prefer my table to be set up as below so that I can easily draw relations off of the invoice number column.

```````````````
Shipment Table
``````````````
Field Name      |   Data Type
----------------+-------------
ID              |   Autonumber or Concat
Ship Date       |   Date
Shipper         |   List Lookup
Invoice Number  |   Text
```````````````

Often times there are multiple invoices on one shipment ID, so in the form I would need the ID, Ship Date, and Shipper fields to be input for multiple Invoice Number records.

I'm not very handy with VBA, and the macro builder doesn't seem to be able to do what I want without going into VBA anyways. How would I tackle this using VBA?

````````````
Sample Data
```````````

ID     |  Ship Date   | Shipper | Invoice Number
-------+--------------+---------+-----------------
13597  |  5/15/2015   |  UPS    |   230136
13597  |  5/15/2015   |  UPS    |   230137
13597  |  5/15/2015   |  UPS    |   230138
````````````

Form Design: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyjLF.jpg

Comment: @HansUp I added sample data and a picture of the form design. The ID is not important as long as it is replicated for the 3 instances of the invoice number record additions. I'll take care of what that will consist of.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  Seems to me you should have a table for shipments with ID, Ship Date, and Shipper fields.  And then a second table for invoices which includes the shipment ID as a foreign key and another field for Invoice Number. One row in shipments could then be related to many rows in invoices.

Comment: @HansUp Good point! I'll give it a shot and reply if I have issues.